# How to get a list of all the Directories on your SD card?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

How to get a list of all the Directories on your SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code to get list if directories

```
public static ArrayList<String> getAllDirectoriesFromSDCard(Activity activity) {
        ArrayList<String> absolutePathOfImageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  


        for (File f : file)
        {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                absolutePathOfImageList.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                }
        }

        // Log.i(TAG,"........Detected images for Grid....."
        // + absolutePathOfImageList);
        return absolutePathOfImageList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By All Directories i think you mean even the child directories in the sdcard, well if yes then heres what you need to do

1) Initialize an ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<String> allDirectories = new ArrayList<String>();
```

2) Copy and Paste this function:

```
    public void listAllDirectories(String path) {

    File tempfile = new File(path);
    File[] files = tempfile.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {
        for (File checkFile : files) {
            if (checkFile.isDirectory()) {
                allDirectories.add(checkFile.getName());
                listAllDirectories(checkFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

3) Call it from wherever you want

```
listAllDirectories(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
    for (int i = 0; i < allDirectories.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(allDirectories.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please the try the following code.

Code :

```
System.out.println(" File List Start" );
File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  
for (int i=1;i<=file.length;i++){
System.out.println(" No. "+i+" : "+file[i-1].getAbsolutePath());
}
System.out.println(" File List End" );
```